# HTML disabled after using media queries

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I have written media queries in this order. But some of my html code is not working, which does not have any relation with this media queries. A html button disabled in responsive view. But after deleting the media queries it is working fine. I have checked the code, all the brackets are closed properly. Is there any strict rule that should follow while writing media queries?

```css
@media all and (max-width:1200px) {

}

@media all and (max-width:992px) {

}

@media all and (max-width:768px) {

}

@media all and (max-width:480px) {

}

@media all and (max-width:320px) {

}
```

Comment: Media queries affect CSS, not HTML, and "not working" is not a technical term.

Comment: Thats why I asked the question. Why it is affecting html?

Comment: The current code posted should not affect anything so the question must be incomplete...

Answer (score 0):

Some possibilities

- If you have absolute positioning to button, you can try removing it
- Position button according to device width in responsive view
- Check if another div or element is overlapping button

Comment: But it is working fine in Desktop view. There is not any div problem.